# Samba: How to prevent Samba-server from auto-providing users /home-directory as a shared-folder?

Tags: directory, samba, home, shared-folders

Like described [here](https://wiki.samba.org/index.php/User_Home_Folders), `Samba`-servers on Linux provide the users `/home`-directory as a shared-folder automatically. How can I prevent this behavior?

> *In the following, the directory containing the `home` folders are shared using the users share name. Each user's home directory is created as a subdirectory on the `\\server\users\` share, such as, `\\server\users\user_name`. This is the same format used in a Microsoft Windows environment and requires no additional work to set up.*

---

I only want to share an explicit declared shared-folder, but **not** the whole `/home/username`-directory of my username. How can I adjust this?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Per @Nasir Riley's answer - That will keep the share from showing to anyone browsing the server for shares.

However, the share is still available if you know that it exists.

It would be much better to simply remove the `[homes]` share from the `smb.conf` file completely, or if you think you may want it in the future comment it out, and restart the samba service.

Answer (score 7):

It is enough to include this line:

```
available = no
```

So the section should look something like this:

```
[homes]
comment = Home Directories
available = no
browseable = yes
writable = yes
valid users = %S
valid users = MYDOMAIN\%S
```

Now you'll never see the home user folder like shared.

Answer (score 1):

In the `/etc/samba/smb.conf` file you'll see a section in share definitions called [homes]. It will look like this:

```
[homes]
comment = Home Directories
browseable = yes
writable = yes
valid users = %S
valid users = MYDOMAIN\%S
```

Make sure that `browseable` and `writable` are set to `no` and restart the smb service.

Comment: Can still connect to it if you know it is there.  Better to simply delete the `[homes]` share definition (or comment it out)

Comment: @ivanivan: You are completely right! I figured out the same issue a few seconds ago. I solved this problem by editing the config within `[homes]` like follows: `create mask = 0000`, `directory mask = 0000`, `invalid users = %S`. Now even the listed users don't have access to the users `/home` anymore. I hope it is a good solution like that?

Comment: @ivanivan: Your solution is better than mine! By deleting the whole `[homes]`-section in `/etc/samba/smb.conf` the `/home`-share is not even visible anymore. In my ugly solution it would still be visible. Thanks a lot! You can post this as an answer!

Comment: If you set `browseable` and `writable` to `no` then `/home` won't appear in that case either but deleting it does the same if that's better for you.

Comment: @user:270732: I tried to set `browseable` and also `writeable` to `no`, but the `/home-directory` still appeared in the list of mapable networks and was still browseable nevertheless. To specify this, it only appeared when I was already logged in into the target directory, but I wanted it to disappear completely. Now everything is fine! Nevertheless, thanks a lot for your help and your kind efforts!